# How to Setup Local Developer Environment for IIS Express, Web API, and an MVC Web project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I'm looking for a solution to facilitate for running a local solution that has a ASP.NET MVC Web Project and a Web API REST service project.

Setting multiple startup projects is saved in the .suo file, and is not checked into the repository since it is a specific user settings file.  Also, IIS Express is configured outside the solution in the current's user's directory.

Any suggestions on how to support this multiple startup project scenario in a team scenario ensuring that the same ports are assigned to everyone that brings down the repository from source control?

**Note**: I do *not* want to move the Web API controllers to the web solution.  The segregation of those two projects is important in this architecture.